# CodeIgniter Encrypt class to java

Tags: java, php, codeigniter, encryption, mcrypt

I am encrypting some data from codeigniter using Encrypt class and this will be send to a java program and need to be decoded there.

php code:

```
    $this->load->library('encrypt');
    $this->encrypt->set_key(SERVER_ENCRYPT_KEY);
    $this->encrypt->set_mode(MCRYPT_MODE_CFB);
    $this->data = $this->encrypt->encode($this->input->post('data'));
```

where `SERVER_ENCRYPT_KEY` is the key.

I found this: [MCrypt for Java](https://github.com/SeRPRo/Android-PHP-Encrypt-Decrypt/blob/master/Java/src/com/serpro/library/String/MCrypt.java) but I could not make it work.
There are other libs that can do this? or maybe an example how to do this using the java version of MCrypt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to avoid CI_Encrypt and use this [PHP-Java-AES-Encrypt](https://github.com/stevenholder/PHP-Java-AES-Encrypt) with small changes: add noise and use 2 types of keys. Also I build a tool to convert the old encrypted data to the new format.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look in the [CI_Encrypt](http://apigen.juzna.cz/doc/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/source-class-CI_Encrypt.html#100-130) class. In addition to calling the **mcrypt** library, it does various non standard things. As an example it runs encrypted data through an own invented  `_add_cipher_noise` method. Also, it seems that the encrypted format have changed with different versions - indicating that this could happen again.

If you are going to use the encrypted data outside codeignite you should not use what looks like codeignites own packaging of mcrypt encrypted data.

Comment: I saw that noise added on encryption and I did the same on java too, but I was wondering if someone did managed to use encrypted data outside of codeigniter. I am trying this to avoid asking +10k customers to reenter some data again. But maybe at the end I will end up in applying an custom encryption method in both sides.

Comment: Notice that the messages you get from the encode call in codeigniter ain't self contained. You need to know upfront what cipher was used to encrypt, when you decrypt. The user might have used a `$this->encrypt->set_cipher();` and you can't deduct that from the message. Also, if **mcrypt** ain't there, it falls back to some other method - this also needs to be handled.

Comment: Are used the default values `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256` for cipher and `MCRYPT_MODE_CBC` for mcrypt mode. Also the mcrypt is installed.